# Lazy enable_if sleeping on the job?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

With the definition shown below, I can call `qget<0>()` or `qget<1>()` using G++ (4.7.2), but `qget<2>` or "higher" will fail with a `no matching function` error. Clang++ (3.2), meanwhile, fails with any of them. I've used *lazy* enable_if as a last resort; though I don't think I *should* need it. I know the code looks a bit odd, but can anyone see the source of the error? (Boost provides the enable_if classes.)

```
template <typename T> struct Tid { typedef T type; };

template <unsigned I>
typename enable_if_c<(I==0),double>::type
qget()
{ return 0.0; }

template <unsigned I>
typename lazy_enable_if_c<(I!=0), Tid<decltype(qget<I-1>())>>::type
qget()
{ return qget<I-1>(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a function or function template as e.g. `ret foo(A, B, C);` or indifferently as `auto foo(A, B, C) -> ret;`, then the `foo` that refers to the entity just declared is not in scope until after the so-called declarator. In your particular case, the return type (be it a late return type or not) is always part of the declarator.

This means that in your last declaration the name `qget` in the return type may refer to the previous declaration (the case for `I==0`) but may never refer to the current declaration. This is why `qget<0>` and `qget<1>` are found, but `qget<2>` is not: when attempting to form the return type of the latter, `qget<1>` is not found because the first declaration is SFINAE'd out, as intended and the second declaration is the current declaration and not in scope. The error results in SFINAE.

My usual solution when this happens (which I have to say is not that often) is to use a `struct` (as an implementation detail) because *all* member functions (and member function templates) are declared inside the definition of a class, from the opening brace on.

That being said, you'll still hit a snag because even though you are using `lazy_enable_if_c` you're still eagerly computing the type of `qget<I - 1>()` (as a parameter to `lazy_enable_if_c`) even when `I` is `0`. Lazily evaluating the identity of said type won't save you.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get an example running using GCC 4.7.2, which insists in not terminating the recursion even when fixing the condition to `I > 0` and using a lazy result (although normally I'd use 4.8), so I can't promise you my solution can be made to work.

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation Luc. I'd also normally use a `struct` too, but in this reduced example I'm trying to explore this avenue as an alternative. I guess I'd be happy to use generic/library structs/classes (like `enable_if`), but I'd rather avoid the bespoke `struct` route this time. I'll wait in case a solution turns up, but you have answered the question.